# How to store and organize uploaded images on webserver?

Tags: server, storage

I am writing a server that allows user to upload images. It appears that most people tend to store those files on the filesystem directly.

My question would be if that really is the way how to do it. I'm not familiar with the capacities of a server but what I'm curious about is e.g. how to make sure that the server does not run out of (hard drive) memory?

I would also like to know how one would organize those files for many different users. Is it enough to just store it like `war/images/<user-database-id>/<uuid-for-image>.(jpeg|png)` by just using the user ID inside the database or are there a lot more things to consider when it comes to storing images?

Comment: What is your stack? e.g. Are you running on Heroku, AWS, other? Do you have a back end data store?

Comment: @CarlosMacasaet At the moment I'm running my web application with the Google App Engine but I'm not having anything else so far to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to use a cloud storage system such as Amazon S3, Google Cloud Storage, Rackspace, or MS Azure.

Using a path like the one you suggested ought to be possible but you could also omit the `user-database-id` if that database already gives you a list of objects owned by that user.

Comment: Just to build on this Google App Engine will not allow full use of the Java SDK. Specifically, you probably cannot use any classes that access the filesystem. In addition, when you deploy your war file, it likely is deployed on multiple physical machines (that may start up and shut down at will) so even if you could access the filesystem, it would not be feasible to do so.

Comment: @Carlos, when using these sorts of services you should be using the appropriate API. These may seem like filesystems to the end user, but there a number of fundamental differences. You shouldn't expect them to behave like one programmatically.